# How to show a Badge on the new orders using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple PWA that fetches the data from the WooCommerce API.

I just want to display a badge that say "NEW ORDER" on the new orders that are being created in an interval of time (For example 1 hour ago).

I am not sure how to achieve this.

I tried to make a function that compares the current date with the date that the order was created, but still I am confused.

Here is the component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/es";
import { Icon, Badge } from "rsuite";

function statusString(status) {
  const lookup = {
    processing: "En proceso",
    "on-hold": "En espera",
    completed: "Completado",
    cancelled: "Cancelado",
    refunded: "Reembolsado",
  };
  return lookup[status];
}

const Order = ({ order }) => {
  const isNewOrder = (orderCreatedDate) => {
    const todayDate = new Date();

    if (moment(todayDate).format("LT") > moment(orderCreatedDate).format("LT")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Link className="order-link" to={"/orders/" + order.id}>
      <div className="order-item">
        <Badge content="NEW"></Badge>
        <h2>
          #{order.id} - {order.billing.first_name} {order.billing.last_name}
        </h2>
        <h3>
          {" "}
          <Icon icon="line-chart" size="2x" /> {statusString(order.status)}
        </h3>
        <h3>
          <Icon icon="calendar" size="2x" />{" "}
          {moment(order.date_created).startOf("hour").fromNow()}
        </h3>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Order;
```

The `isNewOrder()` is the function I tried to create, but failed at it. Not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (moment(todayDate).format("LT") > moment(orderCreatedDate).format("LT")) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
```

The reason this doesn't work as you intend is you are comparing the output of `moment().format()` which takes a moment object and formats it to a string. So you're comparing strings, not dates or moments.

Instead you can use [the difference API](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to compare the two moments, [if you still want to use moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

So your function might instead look like:

```
const isNewOrder = (orderCreatedDate) => {
    const todayDate = new Date();

    if (moment(todayDate).diff(moment(orderCreatedDate))/3600000 <=   1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Note one hour is 3600000 milliseconds. So this gives you `true` for all orders created an hour or less after the current datetime.